# What is VBA's format function equivalent in Google Scripts/Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, number-formatting

I'm having some trouble to achieve next VBA code's goal in Google Scripts (changing the number format of a variable adding zeros at the left up to figures)

```
'VBA CODE
sub addingZeros()
  dim num1 as double
 'Cell A1's value is 1, so I get 0001 
  num1 = format(thisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").range("A1"),"0000")
end sub
```

When I was researching, everything pointed out to use the setNumberFormat function, which is not a solution for me, because makes me to change the number in the sheet and I need only to change the variable value for further purposes... There was only one different solution in those I found, which uses a text function but I couldn't make it work ([link for that solution](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/20127579.html))

I'd like a code similar to this:

```
//Google Scripts CODE
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(`XXXXXXXXXXXXX`);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MySheet');
  var num1 = format(sheet.getRange('a1').getValue(),"0000");
  //Cell A1's value is 1, so I'm expecting to get 0001 
  Logger.log(num1);
};
```

All the help will be much appreciated.
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve a value from a cell and you want to convert the format from `1` to `0001`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `Utilities.formatString` is used.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(`XXXXXXXXXXXXX`);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MySheet');

  var res = Utilities.formatString("%04d", sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()); // Modified

  Logger.log(res)
}
```

- In this modification, the value of `1` is retrieved from the cell "A1" and the format is converted to `0001` using `Utilities.formatString`.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `setNumberFormat` is used.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(`XXXXXXXXXXXXX`);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MySheet');

  var res = sheet.getRange("A1").setNumberFormat("0000").getDisplayValue(); // Modified

  Logger.log(res)
}
```

- In this modification, the format of cell "A1" is changed using `setNumberFormat` and retrieved the display value using `getDisplayValue`.

### Note:

- These modified scripts are the simple modification. So please modify them for your actual situation.

### References:

- [formatString(template, args)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate,-args)
- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)
- [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)

Comment: I was lazy and I thought that '0000' format would work... Thanks, your solution works great

Comment: @Antonio Graterol Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.